# Azure agent on-premise ignores chromedriver in path

Tags: azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Im running robot framework tests in release pipeline running a on-premise agent run as service.

I'm receiving this error even though chromedriver.exe is set in PATH variable.

> WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

I'm running out of ideas

Thank you

Comment: If your desire is to have the error message resolved in Azure. Then please highlight what your setup is in Azure. Without knowing what and how you achieved that, resolving it will require assumptions.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answers below from me or from **A. Kootstra**  resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to provide the executable at the instantiation of the ChromeDriver. In Robot Framework `SeleniumLibrary` this is done using  `executable_path` parameter. This then results in the following example:

```
Create Webdriver    Chrome    executable_path=C:/WebDrivers/chromedriver.exe
Go To    http://cnn.com
```

Comment: Thank you, I have made it work with this setting but I would like to avoid making changes to robot settings if possible.

Comment: This setting could easily be passed to the script using a global variable or variable file. So, that would allow you to have settings for local and server without a need to alter the files themselves.

Comment: I ended up using this solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Changes outside the scripts:**

If you're using **Windows** agent and trying to avoid modifying the files: Copy and paste the `chromedriver.exe` in `C:\Python27\Scripts` folder. Restart the computer and update the agent if it's not up-to-date:

[image]

Adding the `chromedirver.exe` into `C:\Python27\Scripts` also works for `Python3.7` as I know.